# Why isn't it "had handed" in "the girl alleged that her mother handed her over"?

Tags: indirect-speech, backshifting

In the following  reported speech:

> The girl alleged that her mother handed her over to a pimp and was taking Rs 40,000 from him every month.
>   —  [Times of India Newspaper, 1st May 2018](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/shimla/delhi-teenager-blows-lid-off-sex-racket-in-manali-implicates-mom/articleshow/63981265.cms?utm_source=facebook.com&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=TOI&utm_content=om-bm)

Why is it not:

> ... **had** handed her over ...

as per the reported speech rule?

Comment: What is that reported speech rule?

Comment: Indirect Speech...

Comment: You don't have the direct speech version of the story here. Then how can you say the reported speech rules have been violated?

Comment: Muhmud plz click on the link which I put in my question , it will redirect you the article from where I have taken this question.

Comment: There is no reported speech in the question.  By that I mean one cannot surmise that it is. The journalist may not be incorporating the girl's exact words into his/her sentence.

Comment: Backshifting to the past perfect is not mandatory when clarity is not impaired. Here, 'handed her over' obviously precedes the monthly payments and the allegation.

Comment: Because it is not obligatory to backshift from a past tense when reporting speech. It is optional. Thus the rule you refer to is wrong, or at best an over-generalization; it may be a rule that teachers or websites use to teach indirect speech; but this does not mean it actually describes how native speakers report speech.

Comment: @Lambie You might wish to adjust your comment. It would be far more helpful to distinguish 'indirect speech' from 'reported speech' (the former a formatting style using a report verb, the latter just speech relayed in some way, the two not always corresponding) as some poorer grammars treat the terms as strictly synonymous. [Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/reported-speech-p2-1692045#:~:text=Richard%20Nordquist%20is%20professor%20emeritus,level%20grammar%20and%20composition%20textbooks.&text=Reported%20speech%20is%20the%20report,Also%20called%20reported%20discourse.) differentiates well.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, the URL (Nordquist), refers to some authors' research material. To my understanding there is much in common between reported speech and indirect speech. I agree with your views on the reporter and what is being reported, but will they be applicable in language schools? Researchers bring out a new interpretation to the existing ones, but are they being standardized? Would like to learn more about the shifts in rules.

Comment: @Ram Pillai To put it bluntly, Ram, ELU is aimed at linguists; ELL was set up as a needed alternative for those having more basic questions. So where elementary treatments are frankly inadequate/erroneous, there are bound to be dissonances between what students are sadly still taught, and the truer picture. Terminologies will differ (this is sadly true even among professors of linguistics, never mind between their departments and say TESL practitioners). ELU is dedicated to championing the best practice (often arguing about what that might be, but often eschewing non-university approaches).

Answer (score 0):

The news story of the TOI in question was told in the Simple Past Tense. If the reporting verb of a direct speech sentence is in the simple past tense and the sentence is changed into indirect or reported speech, normally there should be a back-shifting of the tense of verbs of the direct speech sentence. If the OP's sentence is assumed to be a reported speech sentence, its direct speech version should have been as follows:

***The girl alleged, "My mother hands me over to a pimp and is taking Rs 40,000 from him every month".***

Comment: But you wrote Incorrect direct speech , It should be  " The girl alleged , " My mother handed me over to a pimp and is taking Rs. 40,000 from him every month ".

Comment: the direct speech which you wrote , it does not make any sense...

Comment: TheMdsami33 is right. The act of handing over the child was performed in the past, she would tell officers "I was handed over to...."

Comment: @TheMdsami33, then why should you worry about the rules of the reported speech alone? Why can't you think about the rules of the simple past and past perfect? When we talk about two things happened in the past, the first incident is expressed in the Past Perfect tense and the second one in Simple Past tense. Such a rule is violated here, isn't it?

Comment: Mari u r absolutely right, but @mahmud using simple present in direct speech...

Comment: @TheMdsami33, how can you say that your quoted sentence is an example of the indirect/reported speech sentence? Why can't it be a narration of the reporter in the Simple Past tense?

Comment: Dear Koya , it is very clear and understood from my given phrase , somebody is reporting what the girl said....